# How to insert this xml data to mysql using LOAD XML

Tags: mysql, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobs>
<job>
<location>Raleigh, NC, US</location>
<title>Implementation Consultant II</title>
<city>Raleigh</city>
<job_type/>
</job>
<job>
<location>Saint Louis, MO, US</location>
<title>Food Service Worker I</title>
<city>Raleigh</city>
<job_type> Permanent </job_type>
</job>
</jobs>
```

Here i cant able to insert the data for job_type into mysql using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in MySQL. Upgrade to MySQL 5.5.46 or higher.

[From official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html):

> Prior to MySQL 5.5.46, LOAD XML did not handle empty XML elements in
>   the form  correctly. (Bug #67542, Bug #16171518)